# Standard connection libraries for MySQL, MSSQL, and Oracle in PHP

Tags: php, database

I'm looking for a standard way to connect to databases in PHP. We've all been there - first start with some rudimentary code to connect/query/iterate/insert/disconnect, then the code grew as the program grew, and it ended up with a mess that's hardly reusable.

I know there are many PEAR, PECL, and other PHP libraries/classes out there that can fit my description - but which ones are maintained, used, and have proven to be bug-free and efficient?

Comment: Can you specify which database brand you're using?  E.g. MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft, PostgreSQL, or a mix?

Comment: Each project has its own requirements, and a lot of time customer is already running a database, so he usually wants to use existing one. In my experience, majority of my customers run either MySQL, MSSQL, or Oracle. If they don't have a database, I suggest they run MySQL, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supprised *Zend_Db* hasn't been mentioned yet...

- PEAR's **MDB2**: very stable, also provides a layer that implements all *MDB2*-supported features in all databases where it can at least be simulated. I've used this one for years with much success.
- Zend Framework's **Zend_Db**: I've just started using the higher levels of Zend's entire DB infrastructure, but it seems to be quite stable and extremely well thought out.
- PHP5's native **PDO**: I've not used it at all, but I believe it is the simplest of all of these. In fact, both *MDB2* and *Zend_Db* can use PDO as an underlying layer.

All of the above implement prepare and execute. Of the above, *MDB2* is the most mature, as it's been around for a long time and is based on *DB* and *MDB*. *Zend_Db* appears to be the most well thought out. I know there are others, but I don't have experience or any knowledge about any of them.

Answer (score 6):

if you're using PHP 5 [try out PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 2):

try [Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) libraries such as [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org) and [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org), both uses PDO as database abstraction layer so they pretty much work on all engine.

Answer (score 1):

These two are the best in my opinion. I can't claim to have tried them all though :)

- [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) (PEAR DB's successor)
- [AdoDB](http://phplens.com/adodb/)

If on Linux you'll need FreeTDS to connect to MSSQL, regardless of the library you end up choosing.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at new DB connection/query objects while trying to decide who to about writing or using new libraries, we decided it was best to write our own. In the end it probably doesn't have the flexibility that many other libraries have, but we have added features such as `GetAll()` which retrieves all of the rows in a keyed array or `GetAllKeyed()` which returns a keyed array with the ID as the key. Another great one is `GetOne()` for use when your select only has 1 column. These have all reduced the amount of code greatly.

One other feature is that when you do a query, it determines what type of query it is (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT`, `DELETE`, etc) and then returns appropriate information (such as `INSERT`, the last insert id or `DELETE` the number of rows deleted).

But we have also copied features such as Prepare & Execute from PEAR:DB.